# C# - Editing Registry Value doesn't work depending on computer used

Tags: c#, registry

I've gone into some troubles modifying a registry value using C#.

Here is the problem :
i'm trying to disable connection through Windows Login & Password using C#.

I did add a registry value inside the registry to make it available or not, depending on a checkbox state.

I had it working on a Windows 10 VM, however, i get the following exception while using it on Windows Server 2012 :

"Access to the registry key '...' is denied."

Here's my code :

```
            System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity userSecurity = new System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity();
            System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule userRule = new System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule("Everyone", System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
            userSecurity.AddAccessRule(userRule);

            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers" + "\\" + @"{60b78e88-ead8-445c-9cfd-0b87f74ea6cd}", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, userSecurity))
            {
                key.OpenSubKey(Const.REG_HKLM + @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers" + "\\" + @"{60b78e88-ead8-445c-9cfd-0b87f74ea6cd}", true);

                if (!paramAuthentication.IsCkbLoginPwChecked())
                {
                    key.SetValue("Disabled", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
                else
                {
                    key.SetValue("Disabled", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                }
                key.Close();
            }
```

And the numerous solutions i found on forums :

1)_ Run as administrator --> Ain't working

2)_ Manually change permissions of the concerned subkey --> Got error "Unable to save permission changes on '...'. Access is denied.

3)_ Make out the current user the owner of the key --> i didn't try that one yet. But some points are disturbing me :
First, this feature must be available for all user. 
Also, i'm creating this key value through FullControl registry right. 
And finally, why would it make it work on Windows Server while it already does on Windows 10 ??

There is definitely something i missed on that. What does exactly mean "take the ownership of a key" ?

Any idea or lesson to provide me ?

Answer (score 0):

Think i found it !

That was point 2 (and actually 3 too).

The point is : by default, the owner of the key seems to be different (depending on Windows Version ? Or did i just change it inadvertently ?)

While the key owner was SYSTEM on the Windows 10 VM, on Windows Server, it was TrustedInstaller. I wasn't allow to change permissions under that owner.
Changing it for the current user allowed me to change permissions and potentially add a new key.

I'm currently trying to make that change using C#.

Remains two questions :

Which owner should i choose to make it possible for all users ?

Is there any possible security issue with changing it ?